# Replace folder permissions with icacls

Tags: permissions, icacls

I want to replace a folder's permissions. First I did this:

```
icacls folder /grant user:(oi)(ci)f
```

Then I want to change the permissions and the inheritance to:

```
icacls folder /grant:r user:(oi)(io)rx
```

After this the permissions for user still are `(oi)(ci)f`.

**Why aren't the permissions replaced?**

Replacing permissions and inheritance with setacl works as expected:

```
setacl -on folder -ot file -actn ace -ace
"n:user;p:read_ex;i:io,so;m:set;w:dacl"
```

---

thanks for your answer. But, this is by design? Or this is a bug?
What's the use of the ":r" switch if the only way you can be sure to replace permissions (and inheritance) is this?

```
icacls folder /remove user
icacls folder /grant user:(oi)(io)rx
```

I've been testing how "icacls /grant" works and I found that icacls writes an entry for every type of inheritance.

Try this:

```
md test
icacls test /inheritance:r
icacls test /grant user:f
icacls test /grant:r user:(oi)rx
icacls test /grant:r user:(ci)rx
icacls test /grant:r user:(oi)(ci)rx
icacls test /grant:r user:(ci)(oi)(io)rx
icacls test /grant:r user:(io)(oi)rx
icacls test /grant:r user:(io)(ci)rx
```

Then to see the ACL:

```
icacls test
```

The result is:

```
test PC\user:(F)
     PC\user:(OI)(IO)(RX)
     PC\user:(OI)(RX)
     PC\user:(CI)(IO)(RX)
     PC\user:(CI)(RX)
     PC\user:(OI)(CI)(IO)(RX)
     PC\user:(OI)(CI)(RX)
```

**So I've found that `icacls /grant:r` replaces permissions only for the same type of inheritance.** In my original question:

```
md test
icacls test /inheritance:r
icacls test /grant user:(oi)(ci)f
icacls test /grant:r user:(oi)(io)rx
```

icacls test gives the output

```
test PC\user:(OI)(IO)(RX)
     PC\user:(OI)(CI)(F)
```

And I think the GUI shows only (OI)(CI)(F) cause it includes (OI)(IO)(RX)

Am I missing something? Is this a bug or by design?

Comment: I cannot find an authoritative source that explains why the `grant:r` command does not replace *all* permissions for the specified user. My *guess* is that it's because Admins need a way to replace a specific permission+inheritance ACE (e.g. Grant Read to Files Only) without touching (or re-specifying) other permissions. It seems the `/reset` or `/remove` switches are provided for the case when all permissions for a user must be replaced. I agree the help text for `/grant:r` isn't very exhaustive on its function.

Answer (score 2):

Your first command grants Full Access to the folder for "This folder, subfolders and files."

The permissions aren't replaced by the second command it grants Read & Execute permissions for **Files only** due to use of the the object inheritance combination `(OI)(IO)`. Apparently you cannot *replace* permissions that apply to "This folder, subfolders and files" with permissions that apply to Files only.

To replace the Full Access with Read & Execute permissions for "This folder, subfolders and files", use the same object inheritance in the second command:

```
icacls folder /grant:r user:(oi)(ci)rx
```